# Can't compile Chromium for android on Debian 9 - Unable to create file. File name too long

Tags: android, debian, chromium

I am trying to compile chromium for android on Debian 9 and I get this error, can someone help me on this?

```
dacod@phoenix:~/Devel/chromium/src$ ninja -C out/Default cast_shell_apk

ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[0/21317] ACTION //third_party/WebKit/Source/bindings/modules/v8:generate...snapshot_external_references(//build/toolchain/android:android_clang_arm)

ninja: error: 

WriteFile(__third_party_WebKit_Source_bindings_modules_v8_generate_v8_context_snapshot_external_references___build_toolchain_android_android_clang_arm__rule.rsp):

Unable to create file. File name too long

ninja: build stopped: .
```

Answer (score 6):

The file system you are building on does not support name sizes long enough to accommodate  the 150 character filename:

> __third_party_WebKit_Source_bindings_modules_v8_generate_v8_context_snapshot_external_references___build_toolchain_android_android_clang_arm__rule.rsp

Typical file systems will support 255 character file names. Here is a reference:

https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux

However, [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/) only supports 143 character file names if it is also configured to encrypt the file names themselves [[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32795/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-filename-and-folder-size-with-ecryptfs)]. Are you building in your home folder and is it encrypted? If so, this may be the reason. To check the file name size, run the following in your build folder:

`$ getconf NAME_MAX .
143`

If it is not 255 you may be building on an ecryptfs partition. Try building in /tmp instead, as it may not be encrypted. You can check this with:

`$ getconf NAME_MAX /tmp
255`

Comment: You can use `ctrl-k` and ``, to format code and `>` to "quote"

Comment: Exactly what @zatoichi commented, I will try to do in another unencrypted partition.

Comment: @zzwyz , I did not understand what you mean